# itextsharp 5.5.13.2 problem showing hungrerian and Polish language

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation, polish

While showing the report  some character are not displaying on PDF

```
case "HU"://Hungearian
     writeText(cb, **"Vevői cselekvési jelentés",** 210, 793, f_cn, 16);
                            

private void writeText(PdfContentByte cb, string Text, int X, int Y, BaseFont font, int Size)
{
    cb.SetFontAndSize(font, Size);
    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, Text, X, Y, 0);
}
```

it shows **"Vevi cselekvési jelentés"**  for first line

Comment: iText supports writing systems that are different from the Western left-to-right writing system eg like Arabic, Indic but only if you include the pdfCalligraph add-on.

Comment: How is your font `f_cn` generated, which encoding did you select?

Comment: @Jazb *"iText supports writing systems that are different from the Western left-to-right writing system eg like Arabic, Indic but only if you include the pdfCalligraph add-on."* - The OP mentioned iText version 5.5.13.2; the pdfCaligraph add-on is for iText 7.x.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use font based on proper code page. For us (greetings from Poland ;) ) [CP-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) does the trick.

Try something like:

```
var font = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, false);
```